# Log4net not inserting data into the oracle database?

Tags: c#, oracle-sqldeveloper, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I tried using log4net for logging info into db and I stuck with it now.Not sure what I am doing wrong.Whatever message i send its not received in the database,neither shows any error

My logger.config below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true "/>
  </appSettings>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender_Oracle"/>
      <appender-ref ref="WebInformaction" />
      <appender-ref ref="WebError" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="WebInformaction" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender, log4net">
      <connectionType value="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
      <connectionString value="Mydatasource" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO EVENTS_LOG (ID,LOG_DATE,THREAD,LOG_LEVEL,LOGGER,MESSAGE,EXCEPTION) VALUES (EVENTS_LOG_SEQ.nextval, :log_date, :thread, :log_level, :logger, :message, :exception)"/>
      <bufferSize value="0"/>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":log_date"/>
        <dbType value="DateTime"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":thread"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="255"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":log_level"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="50"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":logger"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="255"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":message"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="4000"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":exception"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="2000"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <logger name="Informaction">
      <level value="All"/>
      <appender-ref ref="Informaction" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Code to access it:

```
using AuditResourcesTool.Common;
using AuditResourcesTool.Common.Attributes;
using AuditResourcesTool.Common.Enums;
using AuditResourcesTool.Common.Extensions;
using AuditResourcesTool.Common.Models;
using AuditResourcesTool.Common.Services;
using log4net;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AuditResourcesTool.Web.Controllers
{
    [ErrorHandler]
    // GET: Base
    public class BaseController : Controller
        {
            // public readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            public ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(BaseController));
            public ILog ErrorLog = LogManager.GetLogger("Error");
            public ILog InfoLog = LogManager.GetLogger("Informaction");

            public void Warning(string message)
            {
                //logger.Warn(message);
                InfoLog.Warn(message);
                AddToTempData(Alerts.WARNING.ToLabel(), message);
            }

            public void Success(string message)
            {
                //ogger.Info(message);
                InfoLog.Info(message);
                AddToTempData(Alerts.SUCCESS.ToLabel(), message);
            }

            public void Information(string message)
            {
                //logger.Info(message);
                InfoLog.Info(message);
                AddToTempData(Alerts.INFORMATION.ToLabel(), message);
            }
            public void Error(string message)
            {
                //logger.Error(message);
                ErrorLog.Error(message);
                AddToTempData(Alerts.ERROR.ToLabel(), message);
            }
            public void AddToTempData(string type, string message)
            {
                if (TempData.ContainsKey(type))
                {
                    TempData[type] = TempData[type] + Environment.NewLine + message;
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData.Add(type, message);
                }
            }


            public ActionResult Authorize()
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Study");
            }


            public bool IsLoggedIn()
            {
                return SessionService.GetObject(Constants.USER_SESSION_KEY) != null
                    && (SessionService.GetObject(Constants.USER_SESSION_KEY) is UserModel);
            }

            public UserModel GetCurrentUser()
            {
                return this.IsLoggedIn() ? (SessionService.GetObject(Constants.USER_SESSION_KEY) as UserModel) : null;
            }

            public HttpCookie SetCookie(string identity)
            {
                var cookie = new HttpCookie(Constants.USER_SESSION_KEY, identity);
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
                Response.SetCookie(cookie);
                return cookie;
            }

            public string GetCookie()
            {
                var cookie = Request.Cookies[Constants.USER_SESSION_KEY];

                if (cookie != null)
                    return cookie.Value;

                return null;
            }

            public void Remove()
            {
                if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(Constants.USER_SESSION_KEY))
                {
                    HttpCookie cookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[Constants.USER_SESSION_KEY];
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                }
            }


        }
    
}
```

My table for log:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTS_LOG 
(
  ID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, LOG_DATE TIMESTAMP(3) 
, THREAD VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) 
, LOG_LEVEL VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, LOGGER VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) 
, MESSAGE VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) 
, EXCEPTION VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE) 
);
```

It would really great if someone helps me where im doing mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you create the sequence EVENTS_LOG_SEQ for the ID column? As far as I know newer Oracle versions (starting with 12c) have identity columns so you wouldn't need a sequence anymore, you could just define the ID column as an auto increment column.

Comment: Hi @DirkTrilsbeek, yes i have created a sequence and also tried without doing it but it didnt worked. Thanks

Comment: could you try just inserting a row into the log table manually by copy&pasting the insert from the log4net config and replacing the parameters with some test values? Ideally with the same user as log4net will use, to check for authorization issues as well.

Comment: I tried it @DirkTrilsbeek it is inserting, but though log4net it is not inserting. Thanks inadvance

Comment: then I would guess that log4net can't connect to the database. You could use the log4net internal debugging and write that to a file so that you can see where exactly log4net is failing. See here for log4net config debugging: https://thinkrethink.net/2017/07/03/log4net-troubleshooting/

Comment: Not showing any errors in output i even tried this

Comment: not sure whether this is a copy&paste error, but your appender in the config is named WebInformaction, but in the logger you're using the appender-ref Informaction, not WebInformaction. And your root node is before all the appenders, in the config examples in the documentation the root logger is always at the bottom of the config below the appenders. Not sure whether that is relevant though. To be honest, at this point I would start with a minimal logging config into a file. Once that works, add the oracle appender and go on from there.

Comment: log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: No appender named [WebInformaction] could be found.
log4net:ERROR Appender named [WebInformaction] not found.
log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: No appender named [WebInformaction] could be found.
log4net:ERROR Appender named [WebInformaction] not found.